# Javascript how can i do optimize the delay in big array. its have 350000+ item

Tags: javascript, arrays, performance, optimization

I search with the button in the javascript array that has 350,000 item, but there is a delay when searching, especially on mobile devices. Is there any way to optimize this?

```
var findWord = "car";
var wordArray = [];       /* have 350000+ item*/
function func_findInWordArray(item, index, ref){
   return item == findWord;
}
var word =  wordArray.find(func_findInWordArray);
if (findWord == word){
    alert("finded: " + findWord);
}
```

Comment: With an object that large .. I would be using a server side index or database to do the "crunching" and retrieve it in chunks (IE via AJAX).  You could load 1,000 at a time and have an action like click or scroll-stop to retrieve the next 1,000 to make the process more smooth.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the size of your array, the find method requires a lot of operations. For such a number of items, it's better to use a hash table or a BST.

Here are some implementation guides:

[BST](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/js-binary-search-trees)

[Hash Table](https://www.educative.io/blog/data-strucutres-hash-table-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

Somewhat quicker and shorter than the `.find(func_findInWordArray)` is [`.includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes).

```js
var wordArray = Array.from({length:350000}, u=>Math.random().toString(36).substr(2));
var findWord = wordArray[349999];
if (wordArray.includes(findWord)) console.log("found");
```